# Trying to Download Web Content Asynchronously

Tags: c#, .net, http, asynchronous

I'm trying to download things in web asynchronously.

I made class with it's own http client, and created it's object to each of my Tasks.

Tasks run asynchronous and everything is perfect except http client.

I expected them to be completely independent with each other.

But Even though I run it with Task.Factory.StartNew() Method, every http client objects are acting like they are running in synchronous code.

If one class goes to phase the link, every other classes are waiting for the job getting completed.

this is my http helper class

```
    internal class LinkPharsingHelper
    {                        
        public string httpWebGET(string url, string Referer)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request;
            HttpWebResponse response;
            StreamReader readerPost;
            string resResult = string.Empty;
            Uri uri = new Uri(url);            
            request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.Method = "GET";
            request.Referer = Referer;
            request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; Trident/6.0)";
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.KeepAlive = true;
            request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;                                    
            return resResult;
        }
    ...
    }
```

and GetHttpContent Method uses it.

```
        for(int i = 0; i<urllist.Count; i++)
        {                
            int urlnum = i;
            string Th_RootPath = imagerootpath;
            Task.Factory.StartNew(((Action)(() =>
            {                    
                GetHttpContent(urllist[urlnum], Th_RootPath);//Do http content downloading jobs
                this.TotalProgressBar.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
                {
                    this.TotalProgressBar.Value++;
                }));
            })));            
        }
```

I'm want my http jobs to be completely independent.

Comment: Isn't `httpWebGET` method always returning `String.Empty` ? You didn't get the response ever.

Comment: Yeah, your `request` is just lost at the end of `httpWebGET` without ever sending the request.

Comment: If you want to make HTTP requests asynchronously, use [`HttpClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient) with `await` instead. There are examples in the documentation.

Comment: So what is the issue?  You cannot parse the html until the all the text is read.  So as long as each class is running asynchronously you are doing what is needed.  To get the progress you have to create your own HttpWebRequest  that inherits the base class and then add the code in the new inherited class.

Comment: I've edited my http class cause its too long to pasted in here.I just wanted to show http class options and its working fine. The issue is httpWebGet method is not working in same time line. If I run two tasks with http class, one task is waiting for another one. Should I use parallel class?